# query using array

Tags: sql

I have list of array:

```
Dim monthz As String() = {"jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sept","oct", "nov", "dec"}
Dim ko3 As Double, ko1 as integer
ko3 = 0.02
```

Those strings was the name of attribute on my table called "mytable".
i want to update the database using the increment value of `ko3`, using this query:

```
For ko1 = 0 To 11 Step 1
    connection.connectDB()
    sql = "update tbl_coll_penalty set " & monthz(kol) & " = '" & ko3 & "' where year = '" & current_year1 & "'
    acscmd1 = New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(sql, pgConnection)
    acscmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ko3 += 0.02       
Next ko1
```

My problem is I got an error on my query where I select the name of the table
help me pls. tnx in advance.

Comment: Is this visual basic? also if you are getting an error on your query are you sure there is a table called tbl_coll_penalty ?

Comment: ah, sorry for not changing the name of table, pls. ignore the tbl_coll_penalty tnx

Comment: im asking if my query is correct?, b-coz im using ("& monthz(kol) &") this syntax

Comment: could you add the exact error you are getting

Comment: well if your table has a column called 'jan' then your query is correct

Comment: i got an error regarding to the parenthesis, and when i remove the & sign, it says that monthz(kol) does not exist.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken this is written in visual basic right? Also I just noticed you are using ko1 (number 1) in your loop header and kol (letter l) inside your loop, might this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your loop instead: (I think you are using a variable that doesn't exist inside your for loop 'kol')

```
For ko1 = 0 To 11 Step 1
    connection.connectDB()
    sql = "update tbl_coll_penalty set " & monthz(ko1) & " = '" & ko3 & "' where year = '" & current_year1 & "'
    acscmd1 = New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(sql, pgConnection)
    acscmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ko3 += 0.02       
Next ko1
```

Comment: @ Jeremy C.  thank you so much for your help, i didnt notice the variable i used, heheheheh thanks a lot again